# $ \int_{0}^{1} f_n \,dx \geq 1 $ implies $ \int_{0}^{1} f \, dx \geq 1 $

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let assume
$$f_n:[0,1] \to [0,+\infty], $$
be a sequence of measurable functions such that
$$ \int_{0}^{1} f_n \,dx \geq 1. $$
How to show that
$$ \int_{0}^{1} f \, dx \geq 1, $$
Where $f$ is the pointwise limit of $f_n$.

Comment: What is $f$? Is it $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n$?

Comment: @Jacob A: sry. I will edit.

Comment: You can't show that; it is not necessarily the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $f_n(x)=2^{n+1}1_{[2^{-(n+1)},2^{-n}]}(x)$. Then $\int_0^1 f_n=1$, but $\int_0^1 f=0$. The result is true when $f_n\le g$ for all $n$ and some integrable function $g$ (by the reverse Fatou lemma).